# How can you justify html so nicely?

Tags: html, css

Recently I came across [this site](http://web.willbenton.com/writing/2008/better-latex), where the text is justified in a very nice way. How can I do it?

[image: justified text]

Comment: Bring it on! And here silly me, I thought some people might suggest best javascript  and css justify practices, like hyphenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just looking for [`text-align: justify`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-align), no?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see anything special in the CSS other than that style rule.

Answer (score 2):

They use `text-align:justify`, is that what you are looking for?

Here is a shot without `text-align:justify`:

[image: without justify]

And here is with `text-align:justify`:

[image: with justify]

Answer (score 1):

like this:

Html

```
<p>teext</p>
```

Css

```
p
{
align:justify;
}
```

The value "justify" is allowed for the following elements:

```
p, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
```

and table elements

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Dev tools tell me it's:

```
text-align: justify;
```

on the text.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
text-align: justify;
```